# How do I copy all the duplicate lines of a file to a new file in Python?

Tags: python, duplicates, lines

I'm trying to write a code to copy all the duplicates of a file to a new file. The program I wrote checks the first 3 elements of each line and compares it to the next line.

```
f=open(r'C:\Users\xamer\Desktop\file.txt','r')
data=f.readlines()
f.close()
lines=data.copy()
dup=open(r'C:\Users\xamer\Desktop\duplicate.txt','a')
for x in data:
    for y in data:
        if (y[0]==x[0]) and (y[1]==x[1]) and (y[2]==x[2]):
            lines.append(y)
        else:
            lines.remove(y)
dup.write(lines)
dup.close()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xamer\Desktop\file.py", line 80, in <module>
    lines.remove(y)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are trying to remove something that isn't there. The line must have been removed earlier during the looping.

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you say it does: it checks for duplicates through the whole file, not just whether adjacent lines are equal. Which one do you want?

Comment: For your task you can either copy `data` and then `remove` unique lines and duplicates except for the first occurrence (unnecessarily complicated), or you can start with an empty list and `append` duplicated lines. The code you posted tries to do both.

Comment: [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=data%20%3D%20%5B1%20,%202,%203,%204,%205,%202,%206,%207,%203,%202,%208%5D%0Aunique%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%0Afor%20x%20in%20data%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20y%20in%20data%3A%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20x%20%3D%3D%20y%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20unique.append%28y%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20unique.remove%28y%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=1&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) can help you to understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These snippets should do the job you were asking for. At the beginning I thought to create a `duplicated_lines` list and then writing it all at the end. But then I realized that I could optimize the code performance avoiding an additional final loop by just writing the repeated items on the fly

As underlined by another user it is not really clear if you want to check only adjacent double entries or repeated items independently from the position

In the first case - where repetitions are immediately after - this is the code:

```
# opening the source file
with open('hello.txt','r') as f:
    # returns a list containing the original lines
    data=f.readlines()

# creating the file to host the repeated lines
with open('duplicated.txt','a') as f:

    for i in range(0, len(data)-1):
        # stripping to avoid a bug if the last line is a repeated item
        if(data[i].strip('\n') == data[i+1].strip('\n')):
            print("Lines {}: {}".format(i, data[i]))
            print("Lines {}: {}".format(i+1, data[i+1]))
            #duplicated_lines.append(data[i])
            print("Line repeated: " + data[i])
            f.write("%s\n" % data[i])
```

If instead you wanna check repeated lines all along the file this is the code:

```
# opening the source file
with open('hello.txt','r') as f:
    # returns a list containing the original lines
    data=f.readlines()

# creating the file to host the repeated lines
with open('duplicated.txt','a') as f:    
    for i in range(0, len(data)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(data)):
            # stripping to avoid a bug if the last line is a repeated item
            if(data[i].strip('\n') == data[j].strip('\n')):
                print("Lines {}: {}".format(i, data[i]))
                print("Lines {}: {}".format(j, data[j]))
                #duplicated_lines.append(data[i])
                print("Line repeated: " + data[i])
                f.write("%s\n" % data[i])
```